# socket io connecting but not emmiting

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io

i have socket io redis and express pubsub going on, in my local host it works just fine i am using laravel events to publish to redis then socket io is supposed to emit the message, its working okay on local host but on my production server which is an ec2 vm it only gets to connect and i can see a console message 'connected' but it does not emit any events even though messages are being published to redis here is my client and server

```
//client

<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
            var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:3000/');

            socket.on('connect', function(data){
                //socket.emit('subscribe', {channel:'score.update'});
                console.log('connected');
            });

            socket.on('notification.update', function (data) {
                //Do something with data
                console.log('Notification Caught: ', data);

            });




// ]]></script>




//server
var express =   require('express'),
    http =      require('http'),
    server =    http.createServer(app);

var app = express();

const redis =   require('redis');
const io =      require('socket.io');
const client =  redis.createClient();

server.listen(3000, 'localhost');

io.listen(server).on('connection', function(client) {
    const redisClient = redis.createClient()
    redisClient.subscribe('notification.update');

 });
    redisClient.on("message", function(channel, message) {
        //Channel is e.g 'score.update'
        client.emit(channel, message);

    });

    client.on('disconnect', function() {
        redisClient.quit();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the listening of your server:

Change these:

```
var express =   require('express'),
http =      require('http'),
server =    http.createServer(app);

var app = express();

const redis =   require('redis');
const io =      require('socket.io');
const client =  redis.createClient();
```

And

```
server.listen(3000, 'localhost');    

io.listen(server).on('connection', function(client){
    //Code
});
```

To:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

And

```
io.on('connection, function(client){
    //Code
});

server.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Listening on :3000");
});
```